# Hidden character (looks like a bullet) destroys document

Tags: php, database, unicode, utf-8, notepad

I have a problem with a hidden character not showing up either in database (phpmyadmin) nor website. Website has utf-8 character encoding. If I copy/paste the string with the "hidden" character into Notepad I can see it. It looks just like a bullet character but is hidden. What type of character is this and can it be removed with PHP?

The user able to type this character is using Mac and are probably doing a copy/paste from a document (maybe unicode?) into a form on our website and saves it. So this character is not visible with utf-8 encoding but visible if I copy my string into a Notepad document.

This is the hidden character at the end of the string. Looks like a bullet:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the generated output (html)?

Comment: [link](http://www.fz.se/temp/rasmus/character.html) Here's a link. Copy/paste this content into Notepad and you should see the character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the character, then fire up PowerShell and do the following (yes, it's convoluted, sorry):

```
'U+{0:X4}'-f+[char]'<PASTE>'
```

and paste the character where it says `<PASTE>`. It should give you the Unicode code point of that character. You then should be able to write something that removes it from the string, but from my eyes there shouldn't be any input that destroys the document layout, except maybe fun things like RTL markers.

---

Short explanation of the above: `[char]'x'` converts a single-character string to a char, `+` will then treat it as a number (similar to `[int]`, but shorter). The rest is a format string and the formatting operator `-f`.

Comment: It converts the character to a question mark. Doing what you said just gives:

PS C:\Users\user> 'U+{0:X4}-f'+[char]'?'
U+{0:X4}-f?
PS C:\Users\user> ?

Comment: U+2028 This could be it? A google on it shows it's a line separator: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Comment: Could be. This was an attempt to unify the whole CR/LF mess. Some editors can cope with it just fine, others do strange things. HTML should treat it just as any other whitespace, though.